# Error when I open other url in the same window (javascript/html)

Tags: javascript, html, window.open

When I open a URL in the same window and then go back to the older page, then I receive this error:

*Uncaught ReferenceError:  is not defined principal.php:2

Uncaught ReferenceError is not defined*

```
//in principal.php
function btnGoClick(event) {
    window.open('fb.php','_self',false);
}

//in fb.php
function btnBackClick(event) {
    window.open('principal.php','_self',false);
}
```

Comment: is an event when the page load, but is defined...this error is only when I back to the page

Comment: I have replaced window.open with document.location.href = "link". It works!

Comment: answer your question and accept

Answer (score 0):

I have replaced window.open with document.location.href = "link". It works!